# Ionic Cordova - iPhone X safe area has changed with iOS 13+

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ios13

I'm writing an app with cordova, Ionic v1, and AngularJS 1.5.3.

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.3 (C:\Users\User\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0, ios 6.1.0, browser 5.0.4, windows 4.4.3
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 17 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\User\Documents\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.21.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

In the past the new iPhone X came out and I added some code to make adustments for the "safe area".

css

```
body {
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

It was working for me for a long time.

However, I noticed that with the iPhone X and XR with iOS 13.6 I'm having issues with the "safe area".

As I'm using cordova-ios 6.1.0 I'm using WkWebView only.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

[image]

I'm finding that I have to multiply the safe-area-inset-bottom by 4 to make any progress.

```
$calculated_padding_bottom: calc(env(safe-area-inset-bottom) * 2);

body {
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) $calculated_padding_bottom env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has changed to "constant" as of 11.2

```
body {
  padding: constant(safe-area-inset-top) constant(safe-area-inset-right) constant(safe-area- inset-bottom) constant(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

Why are you using Ionic 1?

Comment: This helped with part of the problem. I will write a new question for the other part of my problem.

Comment: Actually it did not change *to* `constant` but *from `constant` to `env`*, see https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Comment: One should still use `env` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env. At least that's what worked for me in plain Capacitor without Ionic.